# multiple arguments in a printf method

Tags: java, printf, double

I am writing a code for my Java class that calls for me to create something that looks like a bill/receipt.
similar to:

```
    Item                    quantity                    price            total
    gum                     10                          $1.49            $14.90
    soda                    3                           $1.00            $3.00
    chips                   20                          $1.25            $20.00
```

I am using the printf(); method. The variables i have declared are

```
    double gumPrice = 1.49;
    float gumQuantity = 10;
    double gumTotal = 14.90;
    double sodaPrice = 1.00;
    float sodaQuantity = 3;
    double sodaTotal = 3.00;
    double chipsPrice = 1.25;
    float chipsQuantity = 20;
    double chipsTotal = 25.00;
```

i need to create a few printf(); statements to list the data in that manner.

This is what i have so far for gum, which is giving me an error.

```
        System.out.printf("%-30s %-10.2f %-10.2f %-5.2f", "Gum",gumQuantity,"$"+gumPrice,"$"+gumTotal);
```

What is the correct way to put a double in a printf(); while listing multiple arguments in one line?

Comment: You're passing strings for the latter two `%f` parameters.

Comment: change `%-10.2f`, `%-5.2f`to `%-10.2s`, `%-5.2s` since `"$"+gumPrice`, `"$"+gumTotal` is a string not double

Comment: @Jonjongot That's going to give the default string representation of a double, though, so it's going to be necessary to to a `String.format("$%.2f", gumPrice)` and similarly for `gumTotal` to make it look right.

Comment: Do you have to use printf instead of print or println?

Comment: @DavidConrad , ahh yes add that as well.

Comment: it is working now, although i need to show 2 decimal places since were using monetary values. It is currently showing $1 i need it to show $1.00

Comment: It's actually a terrible idea to use `double` for monetary values. But see my earlier comment.

Comment: Whats a better method than using double for monetary values? im a begginer.. any information would help.

Comment: java.math.BigDecimal is generally recommended for money. It can represent quantities like 14.90 exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original problem was due to incorrect mixing of two methods of formatting Java output, `String` concatenation and `printf` formatting. As pointed out in comments, `"$"+gumPrice` is a String, not a double. It would have to have a `%s` format, not `%f` in `printf`. However, it would be better to pick one way of doing the formatting, and stick with it.

Going with the `printf` approach, which I think it better in this situation, the output line becomes:

`System.out.printf("%-30s %-10.2f $%-10.2f $%-5.2f", "Gum",gumQuantity,gumPrice,gumTotal)`;

and it prints:

```
Gum                            10.00      $1.49       $14.90
```

If you went with the String concatenation approach, you would need to explicitly convert the `doubles` using a `DecimalFormat` to force the two decimal places.

The reason to avoid `double` for money amounts is that many short terminating decimal fractions can only be represented approximately. Your `gumPrice` is actually 1.4899999999999999911182158029987476766109466552734375, which is very, very slightly different from what you wanted. On the other hand, `new BigDecimal("1.49")` is exactly 1.49. In some situations, especially if you need to truncate rather than round to nearest, the tiny differences introduced by `double` can matter, so `BigDecimal` is safer for currency calculations.

Comment: This answered my question, thank you for the descriptive answer. I learned a lot from this information.