# printf and string concatenation I think; beginner at this future looks bleak

Tags: java, string, printf, concatenation

The code works fine. Just looking for information on how to set up my print f and get the desired results.

signs more than one print f statement(s):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Coupon {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double total = 0;
        double rate = 0;
        double coupon = 0;

        System.out.print ( " Please enter the cost of your groceries:") ;
        total = input.nextDouble();

        if (total < 10)
            rate = 0;

        else if (total > 10.01 && total <=60 ) 
            rate = .08;

        else if (total > 60.01 && total <=150 ) 
            rate = .10;

        else if (total > 150.01 && total <=210 ) 
            rate = .12;

        else if (total > 210.01)
            rate = .14; 

        coupon = total*rate;

        System.out.printf(" You win a discount coupon worth $ %3.2f\n",coupon, "(",rate, "% of your" ,total, "purchase");
        }
}
```

You win a discount coupon worth $1.12. (8% of your purchase price)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thank you for asking. Unfortunately, it seems that your question isn't very clear as it is. As I understand it you have code that works and you want to improve it, but I can't tell what goals for improvement you want to focus on. Would you mind restating what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multiple arguments in a printf method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28709397/multiple-arguments-in-a-printf-method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to set up printf?

The first argument should be a format string with some number (call it *N* here) of format specifiers (starting with percent) marking where you want values to inserted, followed by *N* arguments that provide the values to be inserted.

If coupon, rate, and purchase are to be inserted, your call should look roughly like

```
 System.out.printf(" ... coupon worth $%3.2f (%3.1f %% of your total purchase $%4.2f",
                   coupon, rate, purchase);
```

There are 3 `%f` format specifiers and 3 arguments. Note the literal percent sign is doubled up.

I guessed at the appropriate widths of fields.

Comment: Do you know how to turn a decimal into a % within the System.printf?

Comment: No.  printf is for printing.  Conversion to a percentage is easily accomplished (*(value / total) x 100)* so there's no reason for it to be built in to a print function.